# Express routes work when serving locally but fail once deployed

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, express, google-cloud-functions

I am building a blog using Node js and Express and hosting it on firebase. When I serve the website locally everything works just fine and the html is served as expected. But, when I deploy the server the routes no longer work and the html files can't be found. I'm sure it has to do with how firebase deploy hold the html files.

I'm not really sure where to go from here. I can't really find great guidance on how to set up something like this on the firebase docs.

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions")
const cors = require("cors")
const express = require("express")
const path = require("path")

/* Express with CORS */
const app = express()
app.use(cors({ origin: true }))
app.get("/", (request, response) => {
  response.send("Hello from Express on Firebase with CORS!")
})

//File path consts
const publicDir = "/Users/wilson/wildman-talks-fb/public";
const blogDir = "/Users/wilson/wildman-talks-fb/public/blogs";

app.get("/about/", (req, res) =>{
    res.sendFile(path.join(publicDir, "/about.html"));
});

app.get("/contact/", (req, res) =>{
    res.sendFile(path.join(publicDir, "/contact.html"));
});

app.get("/tools/", (req, res) =>{
    res.sendFile(path.join(publicDir, "/tools.html"));
});

app.get("/five-steps-july-20/", (req, res) =>{
    //res.send(path.join(publicDir, "/five-steps-july-20.html"));
    res.sendFile(path.join(publicDir, "/five-steps-july-20.html"));
})

exports.app = functions.https.onRequest(app)
```

So what is happening is when I deploy the site locally all of the links in my webpage work to other html webpages for my site. When I deploy it on firebase I get 404 errors. I was able to use path.join(__dirname, "../public") and print out all of the files contained there. When i did that these were the files that were there on my local host: [".DS_Store","404.html","about.html","blogs","contact.html","css","five-steps-july-20.html","img","index.html","js","mail","tools.html","vendor"]. After deploying it just returns me a 500 error so I guess that won't help.

Comment: Please edit the question to give more specific information about what isn't working the way you expect.  For example, what specific URL is working locally but not deployed?  What exactly is the response for non-working URLs?

Comment: If you want to serve static content, are you sure you wouldn't rather use Firebase Hosting for that?  It will be cheaper and faster.

Answer (score 0):

Your directories contain absolute paths to your filesystem. Try to use dynamic absolute paths.
Change the paths from

```
  const publicDir = "/Users/wilson/wildman-talks-fb/public";
  const blogDir = "/Users/wilson/wildman-talks-fb/public/blogs";
```

To

```
  const path = require("path");
  const publicDir = path.join(__dirname, "/public";)
  const blogDir = path.join( __dirname, "/public/blogs");
```

Comment: I added it and still nothing. I was able to print out the __dirname when /about is referenced and the dirname is /srv. I'm not exactly sure how it stores the files that I send if it replicates the structure of my folder or if it re-organizes it.